# Weird Error With MASM & Fibonacci

Tags: assembly, masm, fibonacci, irvine32

**I'm fairly certain now that the error is at sub ecx, 3 !!! I was RIGHT! I created a cmp ecx function AFTER the first two calls and BEFORE the fib loop to see if ecx = 0 and if it did skip to the end, since it would have already printed the 3 values**

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
myName              BYTE    "Nathan Campbell ", 0
programTitle        BYTE    "Fibonacci Numbers by ", 0
prompt_1            BYTE    "What is your name? ", 0
prompt_2            BYTE    "Enter the number of Fibonacci terms you would like to see. Please enter a number between [1 - 46]", 0
ec_prompt           BYTE    "EC: Doing something awesome: Setting text color to teal-ish", 0
numFib              DWORD   ?
prev1               DWORD   ?
prev2               DWORD   ?
spaces              BYTE    "     ",0
goodbye             BYTE    "Goodbye,  ", 0
firstTwo            BYTE    "1     1     ", 0
firstOne            BYTE    "1", 0
temp                DWORD   ?
moduloFive          DWORD   5
UPPERLIMIT = 46
LOWERLIMIT = 1

;user's name
buffer              BYTE 21 DUP(0)
byteCount           DWORD   ?

;greet user
hi                  BYTE    "Hi, ",0

;validation
tooHighError        BYTE    "The number you entered is too high! It must be 46 or below. ", 0
tooLowError         BYTE    "The number you entered is too low! It must be 1 or above. ", 0

;EC -> Doing something awesome: Setting  Background Color and Text Color
val1 DWORD 11
val2 DWORD 16

.code
 main PROC

    ;EC: doing something awesome like setting the text color

    ; set text color to teal
        mov eax, val2
        imul eax, 16
        add eax, val1
        call setTextColor

    ; INTRODUCTION
        mov     edx, OFFSET programTitle
        call    WriteString
        mov     edx, OFFSET myName
        call    WriteString
        call    CrLf

        ; EC Prompt
        mov     edx, OFFSET ec_prompt
        call    WriteString
        call    CrLf


        mov     edx, OFFSET prompt_1
        call    WriteString
        call    CrLf


        ; get user's name
        mov     edx, OFFSET buffer  ;point to the buffer
        mov     ecx, SIZEOF buffer  ; specify max characters
        call    ReadString
        mov     byteCount, eax

        ; greet the user
        mov     edx, OFFSET hi
        call    WriteString
        mov     edx, OFFSET buffer
        call    WriteString
        call    CrLf

    ; USER INSTRUCTIONS
topPrompt:
            mov     edx, OFFSET prompt_2
            call    WriteString
            call    CrLf

    ; GET USER DATA
        call    ReadInt
        mov     numFib, eax

    ; Validate user data
        cmp     eax, UPPERLIMIT
        jg      TooHigh
        cmp     eax, LOWERLIMIT
        jl      TooLow
        je      JustOne
        cmp     eax, 2
        je      JustTwo

    ; DISPLAY FIBS

        ; prepare loop (post-test), do the first two manually

        mov     ecx, numFib
        sub     ecx, 3          ; we start at iteration 3, the first two are taken care of by JustOne and JustTwo
        mov     eax, 1
        call    WriteDec
        mov     edx, OFFSET spaces
        call    WriteString
        call    WriteDec
        mov     edx, OFFSET spaces
        call    WriteString
        mov     prev2, eax
        mov     eax, 2
        call    WriteDec
        mov     edx, OFFSET spaces
        call    WriteString
        mov     prev1, eax
        **cmp       ecx, 0          ; Compares to ecx to prevent an error causing it to loop infinitely when 3 is input!
        je      TheEnd**

        fib:
            ; add prev 2 to eax
            add     eax, prev2
            call    WriteDec

            mov     edx, OFFSET spaces
            call    WriteString

            mov     temp, eax
            mov     eax, prev1
            mov     prev2, eax
            mov     eax, temp
            mov     prev1, eax

            ;for spacing (first time it should be % 3, rest %5)
            mov     edx, ecx
            cdq
            div     moduloFive
            cmp     edx, 0
            jne     skip
            call    CrLf

        skip:
                ; restore what was on eax
                mov     eax, temp
                ; if ecx % 3 = 0 call CrLf
                loop    fib
        jmp     TheEnd

TooHigh:
            mov     edx, OFFSET tooHighError
            call    WriteString
            jmp     TopPrompt

TooLow:
            mov     edx, OFFSET tooLowError
            call    WriteString
            jmp     TopPrompt
JustOne:
            mov     edx, OFFSET firstOne
            call    WriteString
            jmp     TheEnd

JustTwo:
            mov     edx, OFFSET firstTwo
            call    WriteString
            jmp     TheEnd

    ; FAREWELL
TheEnd:
            call    CrLf
            mov     edx, OFFSET goodbye
            call    WriteString
            mov     edx, OFFSET buffer
            call    WriteString
            call    CrLf

    exit    ; exit to operating system
main ENDP

END main
```

My current issue is that it works perfectly with EVERY NUMBER!!! (Procs the errors if it's high or low so that's as intended) EXCEPT for 3?

3 Makes it try to do super calculations and basically crashes it. Anyone able to help? I mean it's not too drastic, I've got a 1/46 chance of that error popping up when the assignment is graded (I'll turn it in either way) but I'd really like to know what the heck is going on with the code.

It's calling an integer overflow, I think it happens at the moduloFive, is the div causing a huge error?

Comment: I'll be honest, you guys are fast at editing! I posted it, realized I did the code block wrong, and was editing it but half-way through Alex K. already finished the edit. Very impressed, and thank you!

Comment: FIXED IT!!!



    cmp  ecx, 0   
; Compares to ecx to prevent an error causing it to loop infinitely when 3 is input!
    je      TheEnd